# Mi controlador devuelve un archivo pdf dañando, ¿por que?

Tags: nodejs, pdf, nestjs

en este codigo de controlador, obtengo el base64 del pdf desde el método createPDF del servicio: service.

````
    public async getGiftCardPDF(@Param('id') cardId: string, @Res() res) {
        try {
            const base64String = await this.service.createPDF('web', cardId);

            const fileName = 'demo.pdf';
            res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename="' + fileName + '"');
            res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
            res.setHeader('isBase64Encoded', 'true');
            return res.send(Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64'));
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }```
````